# MySQL field value not displaying correct characters in UTF8

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I tried saving this string

```
ŸeÈ╬fý↔5ƒ1
```

to a field which is varchar(1000) and to a table whose collation is utf8_general_ci

When I tried displaying this field in a textfield, I get this value

```
ŸeÈ?fý?5ƒ1
```

Why is it not correctly showing all the characters?

P.S.

I have set this tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

in the head

Comment: I suspect you should set the collation to the DB then it should be fine:) @arvinsim

Comment: @theunlucky Nope, it didn't work.

Comment: @theunlucky I just discovered that you are correct in a way. But the collation that needed to be set was not the DB but the field itself. I set that field to utf8_general_ci and now it works.

Comment: Superb :) Keep going btw add the answer and make close this posts will helpfulfor all :)  Thanks :)

Comment: I would like to know which DB Engine you are using ?either InnoDB or MyISAM?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the field collation itself needed to be set to utf8. I used

```
utf8_general_ci
```

and it worked.

P.S.

Props to @theunlucky for giving me a clue to the problem.